# Issue working with Timemanager plugin of qgis

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I am  trying to create an animation layer using a csv file, but the layer appears blank with small "time frame size".

Attached images have sample data I am plotting with 'hour4' as the time field.
[image: sample data]
[image: time manager layer setting]

The layer appears blank until I select 'Time Frame Size' as 1 year. Ideally it should work with  'Time Frame Size' = '1 day' as my data is at date level with date ranging from 2016-08-08 till 2016-08-23.

Comment: Based on the screenshots, it seem like the months are missing a leading zero. There might be other things going on with the data.